# Do a regular merge with a merge driver after performing custom operations

Tags: git, maven, merge, git-merge

I want to provide a merge driver, that does a default git merge after changing the remote version of the file.

Background: When merging back bugfixes from a release branch to the integration branch, the maven version in integration branche's pom.xml will conflict. The resolution of this config is to simply keep the local maven version, but not to keep the rest of the file. Keeping the whole local pom file would prevent us from bugfixing it.

Any ideas/hints?

Answer (score 1):

There is a working example of that at [pom-merge-driver](https://github.com/agusmba/pom-merge-driver)
However, it only works how you describe when merging to "develop" branch. If you merge to any other branch, the policy is to use the merging version for the project.
You can tweak the script to work always the same way if that's what you want.

Comment: I managed to write my own pom merge driver. I have built an executable jar file that uses the Maven Model API to read the project version and uses JDOM with XPath to write the project version to the other pom.xml. Afterwards a git merge-file is executed.

Works fine for me.